# Limit maximum incoming connections to a port using iptables

Tags: iptables, port

I have a server that has apache listening on a number of ports. Some ports are used for configuring the server, and another is used to download large files.

My problem is that when I have a large number of clients downloading files, the web interface is uncontactable. I would like to limit the number of clients connecting on the "large file" port so that apache always has available connections to configure the server. A REJECT is fine, the client trying to download the file will back off and retry later. Each client only has one connection open to the server at a time, so limiting by IP won't work.

I know I could put something in front of apache to manage this, but I'd really like to do it in iptables, without adding more software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `--connlimit` with the `--connlimit-mask` option to set a mask of 0.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport XXY -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 --connlimit-mask 0 -j REJECT
```

Where `XXY` is the port that you want to rate-limit connections to.